# Which 3D finite element mesh generator recommend to me?

Tags: math-software, finite-element-method

Which tetrahedral mesh generator recommend you to study finite element method?

I tried to use TetGen. It works well but I can not install tetview to see the meshes because I have a 64bit computer.

I'm need to work with P2 elements in each tetrahedrom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most well-known alternative for TetGen is [Netgen](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/netgen-mesher/index.php?title=Main_Page). Another approach would be to use another software, e.g. [Geomview](http://www.geomview.org/), to visualize the meshes generated by TetGen.

The usage of $\mathbb{P}_2$-basis doesn't in fact set any additional constraints on the mesher unless you're interested in curved boundary elements which are supported at least by Netgen.